# How do the variable names correspond to each other in this example of graphql?

Tags: graphql

Hi I am new to this and trying to understand this.
I am going through the following example on the documentation site.

```
query HeroNameAndFriends($episode: Episode) {
  hero(episode: $episode) {
    name
    friends {
      name
    }
  }
}

{
  "episode": "JEDI"
}
```

from [here](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#variables).
I am getting that we are passing the variable into query. But i am not able to get what is "Episode" in above code in first line, is this some enum or what ?

Secondly, "episode" in the variables dictionary refers to the truncation of "$episode" in first line or it directly refers to the variable passed into hero in second line.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I got it now. "Episode" is the type of variable.
"episode" is the truncation of "$episode" referring to string interpolation.
Thanks.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).